# Mail client for iOS that can show new messages in all IMAP folders

Tags: ios, email, imap

I have a custom email server which is accessible via IMAP. The emails are automatically organized into different IMAP folders on the server.

All these folders show up just fine in most iOS mail applications. However, is there a mail app that can

1) sync all the IMAP folders? Now only the main Inbox folder is synced automatically.

2) get some sort of unified inbox showing all new mail from all the IMAP folders?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more about programming that needs to be done on the IMAP server end and not configuring the Mail client.

Comment: The unified inbox would require your server to expose a folder that contains all mail (or at the least, all new mail). As far as syncing, that's how Mail.app  works with all IMAP servers.

Comment: These features can be done with a email client, source: I have an android mail program that can do these. Does somebody have experience with some other email app for IOS which would provide these features?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect your new query, then. As it stands the answer is Mail.app cannot do what you're asking.